# Using PHP to auto refresh webpage

Tags: php, page-refresh

I need to automatically refresh the page so that a bot reading it,  the displayed text will  be different each time. I have this but I need to know if I can improve on it?

```
<?php

$deaths = array("with a potato.", "by using a truck and running them over.", "with a gun, bang bang.", "by stuffing a mouldy lemon in their mouth.", "by throwing multiple knives at them.", "by tying them up and forgetting about them.", "by throwing them off a building onto a cactus.");
$death=array_rand($deaths);
echo $deaths[$death];

$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 0.5; URL=$url1");

?>
```

Comment: Any headers should be sent before any output (`echo`).

Comment: A good bot should be able to ignore Refresh-headers in the HTTP request, just so you know. If you're using this to keep bots out or something, then it's probably not the right way. If it's supposed to refresh for all types of clients, then it should be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `header("Refresh:0");`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But he asked how to improve his code.

Answer (score 0):

- The fact you chosed server side refreshing is a good choice because it is faster than the client side refreshing such as with JavaScript (`window.location.reload()`) or HTML (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />`). For more information about this subject, I suggest you to read this interesting article ([[Client-Side vs. Server-Side Rendering]](http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/))
- You design this for a bot, so why to wait before refreshing ?
- If you have within your page other PHP scripts that that must not be cached by the client browser or any proxy caches between the server and the client browser, you can add this line to your page: `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");`
- Also, as it was mentioned on the comment of your question:

> header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by
>   normal HTML tags,

- Since you refresh for the same URI, do not give much work to your server. I mean, remove this instruction: `$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

Given these facts, I suggest to change your code as follows:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //if 3rd point is satisfied
header("Refresh: 0");
$deaths = array("with a potato.", "by using a truck and running them over.", "with a gun, bang bang.", "by stuffing a mouldy lemon in their mouth.", "by throwing multiple knives at them.", "by tying them up and forgetting about them.", "by throwing them off a building onto a cactus.");
$death=array_rand($deaths);
echo $deaths[$death];
?>
```